# Can I have multiple response variables in FORMULA structure?

Tags: r

I'd like to copy this code, except use a formula instead of `x` and `by`

```
assets <- data.frame(asset.class = c("equity", "equity","equity",
                                     "option","option","option",
                                     "bond", "bond"),
                     rating = c("AAA", "A", "A", "AAA", 
                                "BB", "BB", "AAA", "A"),
                     counterparty.a = c(runif(3), rnorm(5)),
                     counterparty.b = c(runif(3), rnorm(5)),
                     counterparty.c = c(runif(3), rnorm(5)))

aggregate(x = assets[c("counterparty.a", "counterparty.b", "counterparty.c")],
                       by = assets[c("asset.class", "rating")],
                       FUN = sum)
```

I tried this `aggregate(counterparty.a + counterparty.b + counterparty.c ~ asset.class, assets + rating, sum)` but it didn't work. How do I add multiple response variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cbind`

```
out1 <- aggregate(cbind(counterparty.a, counterparty.b,  counterparty.c) ~ 
             asset.class + rating, assets, sum)
```

---

Or specify `.` to include all other columns

```
out2 <- aggregate(.~ asset.class + rating, assets, sum)
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

It can be done more easily with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
assets %>%
      group_by_at(1:2) %>%
      summarise_all(sum)
```

---

When we do the `+` on the `lhs` of the `~`, it is doing aggregation into a single column by collapsing rows both horizontally and vertially within the group similar to the one below

```
assets %>% 
     group_by(asset.class, rating) %>%
     summarise_all(sum) %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     mutate(rsum = rowSums(.[3:5])) %>%
     select(asset.class, rating, rsum)
```